# Replace messy str with clean str from another dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains

I have 2 sets of dataframe, and i want to clean df1['Fruits'] if it contains df2['Fruits'] string

```
df1
Name    Fruits
--------------
Dina    Pineapple, [Y*]
Maria   PTC*, Apple
Johny   Durian, 1-6
Johny   5,6 Rambutan
Maria   Apple (Red), [Y] *
Dina    [Y] *, Peach88
Dina    Kiwi/Qiwi, PS*

df2
Fruits      tag
-------------
Apple       20
Pineapple   30
Rambutan    40
Durian      50
Apple (Red) 25
Peach88     55
Kiwi/Qiwi   25
```

i've tried

```
df1.loc[df1['Fruits'].contains(df2['Fruits']),'Fruits'] = df2['Fruits']
```

but it shows

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

So what i expected to get is

```
df1
Name    Fruits
--------------
Dina    Pineapple
Maria   Apple
Johny   Durian
Johny   Rambutan
Maria   Apple (Red)
Dina    Peach88
Dina    Kiwi/Qiwi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.extract`:

```
reg = '(%s)' % '|'.join(df2['Fruits'])
# Make regex expression using df2['Fruits']
df1['Fruits'] = df1['Fruits'].str.extract(reg)
```

Output:

```
    Name     Fruits
0   Dina  Pineapple
1  Maria      Apple
2  Johny     Durian
3  Johny   Rambutan
```

Explanation of `'(%s)' % '|'.join(df2['Fruits'])`:

- `'|'.join(df2['Fruits'])`: creates `|` separated words for `or` operation in regex. Returns `Pineapple|Apple|Durian|Rambutan`
- `(%s) % ...` : This is called *string formatting*, and equivalent of:

  - `str.format`: `'({})'.format('|'.join(df2['Fruits']))`,
  - or more implicit (but less pythonic) `'(' + '|'.join(df2['Fruits']) + ')'`
  - all of which returns `(Apple|Pineapple|Rambutan|Durian)`, a *capture group*, mandatory for `pd.Series.str.extract` to know what to extract.

Comment: works great! thank you!, i will have to look into regex

Comment: after googling i cannot found how `'(%s)' %` works, i know that `( )` are to group multiple tokens together and `'|'` are the separator, but i couldn't find %s and %, can explain abit? :)

Comment: @espifi059espifi059 I've updated the answer. Please let me know if anything is unclear :)

Comment: thank you so much!, however i've encouter another issue is that, if the fruit string contains parenthesis (i've updated my question), and when i run `str.extract`, it couldnt match the string, so i do a workaround to i replace `(Red)` with `iii` and replace back after the extract process. question is do i need to escape the parenthesis?

Comment: @espifi059espifi059 Yeap. the parenthesis are interpreted as an indicator of capture group when it comes to regex. Making `(Red)` into `\(Red\)` should work :)